# Points appear in wrong country (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm working on an assignment in QGIS where I'm supposed to measure the home range of 20 birds in southern Sweden. These birds had GPS trackers on them for some months back in 2014. When I open my CSV file in QGIS they appear in Italy instead of Sweden. I'm completely new to QGIS so I'm probably doing something really basic wrong. I've set all layers to the same coordinate system (the map, QGIS and the points) but I'm beginning to suspect that there is something wrong with my coordinates, maybe I need to convert them somehow. I'm going to try and add some pictures of how it looks in both Google Sheets and in QGIS. I've tried several different coordinate systems:

WGS 84 / UTM zone 32N EPSG:32632
WGS 84 EPSG:4326
WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator EPSG:3857
SWEREF99 EPSG:4619
SWEREF99 TM EPSG:3006

But none of them seem to work for me. These are raw coordinates in decimal degrees according to my supervisor.

[The google sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZoUu.png)

[image: How it looks like in QGIS, point in Italy]

[image: When adding the CSV-layer]

[image: More of adding CSV-layer]

Comment: The latitude and longitude definitely are not in decimal degrees. If they were the values would be between -180 and 180 for longitude, and -90 and 90 for latitude. Yours look to me in the tens of millions.

Answer (score 7):

Seems like the decimal degrees miss the decimals point. So `5543159` should be `55.43159` (°N), and similarly for the easting.

This places your points about 9 km northeast of Trelleborg:
[image]